# How To Get Music To Be Streamed Online With Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, streaming, android-view

I have been doing some android stuff today anyway that's not the point lol I have worked out how to get a song or app to run in the background now what I want to archive is to start streaming from my radio station which is on a shoutcast server.

How would I do this?

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MyService extends Service {

        private static final String TAG = "MyService";
        MediaPlayer player;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Streaming Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for listening in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
            player.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Streaming Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
            player.start();


        }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to set the URI to the `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: No since I don't think it would work guess it's worth a try I try and let you know how that goes